# LDAPBundle Bad Creditential

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I'm using the **LdapBundle** ([link](https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle)).

When I try log in, I always get a Bad Credential error. And in the log there's always the same error, so I can't debug.

My *security.yml*:

```
 security:
  firewalls:
    restricted_area:
      pattern:          ^/
      anonymous:        ~
      provider:         ldap
      imag_ldap:        ~
      logout:
        path:           /logout
        target:         /

  providers:
    ldap:
      id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

  encoders:
    IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser: plaintext

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/,               roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY} #IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY

imag_ldap:
  client:
    host: 192.168.100.200
    port: 389
    version: 3 # Optional
    username: Administrateur # Optional
    password: Exodia2015 # Optional
#    network_timeout: 10 # Optional
    referrals_enabled: true # Optional
    bind_username_before: true # Optional
#    skip_roles: false # Optional

  user:
    base_dn: cn=Users,dc=order,dc=heig-vd,dc=local
#    filter: (&(foo=bar)(ObjectClass=Person)) #Optional
    name_attribute: uid
  role:
    base_dn: ou=Users,dc=order,dc=heig-vd,dc=local
#    filter: (ou=group) #Optional
    name_attribute: cn
    user_attribute: member
    user_id: dn

  user_class: IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser # Optional
```

My **Windows** server AD configuration:

- IP: 192.168.100.200
- Port (default): 389

It doesn't accept anonymous bin connections.

I can access the server using the same configuration with a LDAP client.

**EDIT (after Fidan Hakay comment)**

I have tried with `ou=Users,dc=order,dc=heig-vd,dc=local`.
But same error.

The dev.log :

```
   [2015-04-19 09:41:07] request.INFO: Matched route "login_check" (parameters: "_route": "login_check") [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] ldap_connection.ERROR: LDAP returned an error with code 49 : Invalid credentials [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Bad credentials [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] request.INFO: Matched route "login" (parameters: "_controller": "IMAG\LdapBundle\Controller\DefaultController::loginAction", "_route": "login") [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" (parameters: "_controller": "web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction", "token": "35247e", "_route": "_wdt") [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
    [2015-04-19 09:41:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: In the base_dn for the users, can you test with `ou=Users,dc=order,dc=heig-vd,dc=local` instead of `cn=Users,dc=order,dc=heig-vd,dc=local` (just like in the role config) ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used fr3d Bundle works perfectly.
[You can find this bundler here](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle)